# Which real numbers have $2$ possible decimal representations?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I know that all positive and negative whole numbers have $2$ possible decimal representations. For example, $1+1+1+1$ could be represented as $4$ or as $3.99999...$ (I believe $4.000..1$ isn't a thing, right?).

All terminating decimal numbers have $2$ representations as well, for example $1.5$ is the same as $1.4999..$ However, I can't really see how you would make a second representation for non-terminating decimals (especially irrational numbers) and zero.

Comment: The 'ambiguity' arises only in the situations you describe because $1 = 0.\bar{9}$.

Comment: This question reduces down to when does the sequence of digits $\{d_1, ..., d_{\infty} \}$ not equal the sequence of digits of the limit $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n= 1} \frac{d_n}{10^{n-1}}$

Comment: As you have mentioned all non-zero terminating decimals have two representations. Apart from this all other real numbers have only one decimal representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decimal representation represents the number that the corresponding series converges to. For a number $x$ whose standard representation doesn't terminate, using any digit other than the one in its standard representation at any point in the series would make it impossible for the series to converge to $x$: If a greater digit is used, the partial sum is greater than $x$, and the remaining terms are all positive and hence can't make the series converge to $x$; and if a smaller digit is used in the $n$-th digit after the decimal point, the result is less than $x$ by more than $10^{-n}$, and the remaining terms can add up to at most $10^{-n}$, so again the series can no longer converge to $x$. Thus each digit is uniquely determined by $x$ unless the standard representation terminates.

Comment: zero seems to be a little different though as it does terminate but I don't think it has a second representation

Comment: @Ovi: You're right. I didn't prove that all terminating numbers have a second representation, only that all non-terminating numbers don't. Also my proof is technically only valid for positive numbers, but negative numbers are just positive numbers with a minus sign.